# Using the page's query params as params in the page level query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

In gatsbyJS there [is a way](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/recipes/querying-data/#querying-data-with-a-page-query) to specify page level queries but from whatever i've read only way to pass params to the gatsby query is when creating the page (via page context).

For example, below $slug is passed to the page when creating it. Is there another way to pass $slug (maybe via a query param value).

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String) {
    mdx(frontmatter: {slug: { eq: $slug }}) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        author
      }
      body
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Can you clarify this part: "Is there another way to pass $slug (maybe via a query param value)."?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I open this new page /search?slug=test and when search loads i read query param `slug` and use that to query within the graphql query (and load the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I open this new page /search?slug=test and when search loads i read
> query param slug and use that to query within the graphql query (and
> load the page)

The short answer is that you can't since you are on the same page (`/search`), which is created and populated using a Gatsby page query in the build-time, so there's no way that you can change that "static" query with a dynamic content coming from a URL parameter.

What you can do, however, is to use plain JavaScript to get the URL parameter and use a dynamic filter to change the result of the page query and display it as you wish in the `/search` page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FerranBuireu. When you say "dynamic filter to change the result of the page query", could you point to some examples?  Would you mean get all the data. and then filter out according to the query parameter before display?

Comment: I've recently answered a similar question which the workaround may fit you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66221048/5585371 Summarizing, I mean, getting all the data and using the `filter` loop to get the needed data before displaying it